# Number of nodes with an even number of children in an ordered tree (AKA Plane Planted Tree)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am looking for verification for my attempt at the solution. I have found that my answer disagrees with an answer I found here: [Extract Coefficients From A Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233170/extract-coefficients-from-a-function)

**Problem at hand**: For a plane planted tree $T$, let $h(T)$ denote the number of nodes of T which have an even number of children. For each $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, determine the average value of $h(T)$ among all the PPTs with $n$ nodes. (This question can be found in Chapter 8 of David Wagner's *Combinatorial Enumeration* notes from CO 330 in University of Waterloo).

**Attempt at Solution**: Let $\Omega$ be the set of all plane planted trees. Let $n(T)$ denote the number of nodes in a tree $T$. Define the bivariate generating function $U(x,y)$ by
$$U(x,y) = \sum_{T\in \Omega}x^{n(T)}y^{h(T)}.$$

We may decompose $\Omega$ as follows: if the root vertex of $T$ were removed, then $T$ would correspond to a $k-$tuple of trees $(T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_k)$ for some $k\geq 0$ (where we take the convention that $T_0 = \{\}$). So,
$$T \leftrightarrow (T_1,\ldots,T_k)$$
if $T$ is not the tree with one vertex.

Moreover, our weights extend as follows:
\begin{align*}
n(T) &= 1+n(T_1)+\dotsb+n(T_m)\\\
h(T) &= 
\begin{cases}
h(T_1) +\dotsb + h(T_{m}) & \text{$m$ odd}\\
1+h(T_1)\dotsb +h(T_m) & \text{$m$ even}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

and so
\begin{align*}
W(x,y) &= \sum_{k\geq 0} x\left[\sum_{(T_1,\ldots,T_{2k})}x^{n(T_1)+\dotsb+n(T_{2k})}y^{1+h(T_1)+\dotsb+h(T_{2k})}+\sum_{(T_1,\ldots,T_{2k+1})}x^{n(T_1)+\dotsb+n(T_{2k+1})}y^{h(T_1)+\dotsb+h(T_{2k+1})} \right]\\
&= \sum_{k\geq 0}x\left[ yW^{2k}(x,y)+W^{2k+1}(x,y) \right]\\
&= x\frac{y+W(x,y)}{1-W(x,y)^2}
\end{align*}
We would like to find $T_n = \{T\in\Omega: h(T) = n\}$. So we look for $$T_n =[x^n]\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}W(x,y)\right |_{y=1}$$
Hence, if we let $G(u) = \frac{y+u}{1-u^2}\in \mathbb{Q}(y)$ and hence
$$W(x,y) = xG(W(x,y))$$
so by the Lagrange Implicit Function Theorem,
\begin{align*}
[x^n]\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}W(x,y)\right |_{y=1} &= \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[x^n]W(x,y)\right |_{y=1}\\
&= \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]G(u)^n\right|_{y=1}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(u)^n\right|_{y=1}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\frac{n}{1-u^2}\left[\frac{1+u}{1-u^2}\right]^{n-1}\\
&= [u^{n-1}]\frac{1}{1-u^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-u}\right]^{n-1}\\
&= \sum_{k= 0}^{n-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^{n-k}
\end{align*}

I realize I have to divide it by the number of PPT's with $n$ nodes to find the average, which is not too much of a concern. My main concerns are: 1) Is my attempt correct? 2)Is there a closed form for the final binomial summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can  actually simplify the  computation of the  generating function
quite a bit. We have by inspection that
$$T(z) = uz + z \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)^2} + uz \frac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)^2}.$$
This is the species
$$\mathcal{T} =
\mathcal{Z}\times\mathfrak{S}_{\text{odd}}(\mathcal{T})
+ \mathcal{U}\mathcal{Z}\times\mathfrak{S}_{\text{even}}(\mathcal{T}).$$
where the even sequence operator includes the case of zero subnodes. (The reason I wrote the functional equation the way I did was to have the base case of the recursion be clearly recognizable.)

We  seek  $$\left.\frac{d}{du}  T(z)\right|_{u=1}$$ so  re-write  the
above to prepare for differentiation.
$$T(z) - T(z)^3 = uz - uz T(z)^2 + z T(z) + uz T(z)^2$$
or
$$T(z) - T(z)^3 = uz + z T(z).$$

Differentiate,
$$\frac{d}{du}  T(z)
- 3 T(z)^2 \frac{d}{du}  T(z)
= z + z \frac{d}{du}  T(z).$$
Put $u=1$ and introduce $$G(z) = 
\left.\frac{d}{du}  T(z)\right|_{u=1}$$
and $S(z) = T(z, 1)$ so that $S(z)$ has the functional equation
$$S(z) = z + z \frac{S(z)}{1-S(z)}
\quad\text{or}\quad
S(z)-S(z)^2 = z.$$
This gives
$$G(z) - 3 S(z)^2 G(z) = z + z G(z)$$
or
$$G(z) = \frac{z}{1 - 3 S(z)^2 - z}.$$

We seek
$$q_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} G(z) dz$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{z}{1 - 3 S(z)^2 - z}
dz.$$

Put $w = S(z)$ so that the functional equation yields
$$w(1-w) = z.$$
This gives
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1-2w}{w^{n+1}(1-w)^{n+1}} 
\frac{w(1-w)}{1 - 3 w^2 - w(1-w)}
dw$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1-2w}{w^n(1-w)^n} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)(1-2w)} dw.$$
which finally becomes
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^n(1-w)^n} 
\frac{1}{1+w} dw.$$
For the residue from the pole at zero use the following series expansion:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {k+n-1\choose n-1} w^k
\times \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k w^k.$$
The coefficient $[w^{n-1}]$
is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k+n-1\choose n-1} (-1)^{n-1-k}.$$
This gives the sequence
$$1, 1, 4, 13, 46, 166, 610, 2269, 8518, 32206, 122464, 
467842, 1794196,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A026641](https://oeis.org/A026641). By the looks of that entry we have the correct result.

This formula matches the one obtained by the OP.

There is another computation in the same spirit at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811821/generating-function-for-vertices-distance-from-the-root-in-a-planar-tree).

**Addendum.** This calculation can also be found at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233170/).

Comment: Marko, thank you for the response and the effort you took to explain this to me. Would you know how to prove that the two answers are the same however?

Comment: Surely you do not mean the binomial coefficients? The complex integral is from page 167/168 of Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* (second edition) where we see that the LIF is really just the Cauchy Residue Theorem. So I decided we may as well apply it directly. The justification is in the Wilf book, same page. The second line where you compute $W(x,y)$ is exactly the same as my functional equation. With species it is easier to spot what is happening quickly.

Comment: My apologies. I am looking for a less "analytical" proof as my background in complex analysis leaves much to be desired.

Regardless, thank you for the time you took to help me.